# ListViewWebPart FilterString not working?

Tags: xslt-list-view-web-part

I'm having some major hair pulling trying to get this to work, basically, I dynamically create a PublishingPage and insert a ListViewWebPart in it and target a List I have, all is fine, but the problem is, I can't get the FilterString to work at all, I'm having the exact same problem as this person in this unanswered thread:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/8469caa6-a454-4768-8a50-4cd244e6541b

Does anyone have any clues?

This is how I'm specifying it"

listwp.FilterString = "FilterField1=Title&FilterValue1=HelloWorld";

Comment: Just a thought - if you manually add that to your URL on which the web part is displayed as part of the query string, does the filter work?